# Symbolicate iOS stack on runtime

Tags: ios, crash

Is there a way to symbolicate symbols on runtime for iOS?

I use NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler for getting crash call stack but I would like to map the addresses reported to actual functions and trace them in a log file.